# How can I update my Database using AJAX after the user has entered text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created a table which has a column for notes, the notes are from a MySQL table and displayed. When the user clicks on the notes it'll convert to an input box and allow them to edit the text. How would I then update my table with the new data that's been entered, so when the user clicks off of the input box they've just entered text in, it'll update the notes column using the correct row ID

Here is my code at the moment...

**Javascript**

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
      $("#loading").hide();
      //acknowledgement message
      var message_status = $("#status");
      $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
          var field_id = $(this).attr("id") ;
          var value = $(this).text() ;
          $.post('scripts/update-jobdiary-notes.php' , field_id + "=" + value, function(data){ //change this to your liveupdatingpage.php
              if(data != '')
              {
                  message_status.show();
                  message_status.text(data);
                  //hide the message
                  setTimeout(function(){message_status.hide()},1000);
              }
          });
      });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<td data-editable contenteditable="true" id="note_text_db_column:<?php $note['notes_id']; ?>"><?= $note['notes_text']; ?></td>
```

**PHP**

```
//DATABASE CONNECTION
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    //database settings

    foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)
    {
        //clean post values
        $field_id = strip_tags(trim($field_name));

        //from the fieldname:user_id we need to get user_id
        $split_data = explode(':', $field_id);
        $data_id = $split_data[1];
        $field_name = $split_data[0];
        if(!empty($data_id) && !empty($field_name) && !empty($val))
        {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ser_diarynotes SET notes_text = ? WHERE notes_id = ?"); //here just change name of your table and name of your unique_column
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $val, $data_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            echo "Updated";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid Requests";
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Call the ajax, on onblur event of textarea

Comment: call ur ajax function on focusOut from the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets me modify your code further with an alternative js and updated html in order to capture:

> 1. **unique ID** of your content. assuming each record has to have a unique id column for easy update
> 2. the **content** being edited

Here is a sample HTML

```
<style>
#status { padding:10px; position:fixed; top:10px; border-radius:5px; z-index:10000000; background:#88C4FF; color:#000; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; margin-bottom:10px; display:none; width:100%; }
#loading { padding:10px; position:absolute; top:10px; border-radius:5px; z-index:10000000; background:#F99; color:#000; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; margin-bottom:10px; display:none; width:100%; }
</style>

 <div id="status"> </div>
 <div id="loading"></div>

<table id="tableID">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <!--Edit below by specifying notes_text column and notes_unique_id-->
    <td data-editable contenteditable="true" id="note_text_db_column:<?php echo $note['notes_unique_id']; ?>"><?php echo $note['notes_text']; ?></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JavaScript that will pass the two variables to your PHP page to update on db

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
    //acknowledgement message
    var message_status = $("#status");
    $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
        var field_id = $(this).attr("id") ;
        var value = $(this).text() ;
        $.post('liveupdatingpage.php' , field_id + "=" + value, function(data){ //change this to your liveupdatingpage.php
            if(data != '')
            {
                message_status.show();
                message_status.text(data);
                //hide the message
                setTimeout(function(){message_status.hide()},1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
});
</script>
```

and now Your **PHP** sample page to update your data

```
<?php  
//Your connection
$conn = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'db_user', 'user_password', 'your_db'); 

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    //database settings

    foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)
    {
        //clean post values
        $field_id = strip_tags(trim($field_name));

        //from the fieldname:user_id we need to get user_id
        $split_data = explode(':', $field_id);
        $data_id = $split_data[1];
        $field_name = $split_data[0];
        if(!empty($data_id) && !empty($field_name) && !empty($val))
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE your_table SET $field_name = ? WHERE column_id = ?"); //here just change name of your table and name of your unique_column
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $val, $data_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            echo "Updated";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid Requests";
        }
    }
} 

else {
    echo "Invalid Requests";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hiya, Thanks for your input. I'm implemented the code you suggested and I'm getting  'Invalid Requests' pop up. I've updated my question/code have I done anything obviously wrong/different to your code?

Comment: Hi, you getting the error `Invalid Requests` because the php page is not receiving something from HTML page i.e. `if(!empty($data_id) && !empty($field_name) && !empty($val))` . ensure the two variable are captured, and also the note_text column name is captures as it is in the db.. Check this line  `<td data-editable contenteditable="true" id="note_text_db_column:<?php $note['notes_unique_id']; ?>"><?php $note['notes_text']; ?></td>`

Comment: check `id="note_text_db_column:` in your HTML change to the column name you have in your DB

Comment: echo out the results in your html code `<?php echo $note['notes_id']; ?>`

Comment: I've echo'd out the results and now i'm getting a fatel error on line 32 which is ```$stmt->bind_param("si", $val, $data_id);```

Comment: try `<?= $note['notes_id']; ?>` . in shot we try to ensure they return some values. you can test it on an open space to see if return some value

Comment: Yeah, it has got the notes_id. I've just echo'd it out and it's returned the right value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208070/discussion-between-ben-smith-and-omari-victor-omosa).